# Searching Contacts by string

Tags: apex

I need to populate a contact lookup field based on given string name only.
I.e. Web-to-lead form will arrive with a string name - This string will be needed to transfer into the contact lookup field.

is there any way to find to search the contact within the system and return the Contact ID to other field?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you getting the search string? Once you get the string fire a jquery function which calls a remote function(pass the string here) and then query and return the contact

Comment: Hey, Thanks! Is there any chance you could send an example?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_example.htm